# Debian: Get list of installed packages while in rescue mode

Tags: debian, backup, package-management, dpkg, rescue-disk

How can I get a a list of installed packages from a debian setup which is mounted to /mnt/ while using a rescue mode?

Scenario: Server crashed, only rescue mode possible. Setting up a new server, migrate data from old server to new with rsync.

But how to install all packages on the new server which were installed on the old server (yeah, rescue mode only)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the filesystem that you are recovering from is in a good state and wasn't malware infected or something, then just try doing a `chroot /mnt /bin/bash`, that should give you a shell that is in the rescued filesystem.  From there you could do a `dpkg --get-selections > packages`.

You can also give the `--admindir=dir` option to dpkg to point at another directory.  So you should be able to do something like `dpkg --admindir=/mnt/var/lib/dpkg --get-selections`

Comment: Another option is to use `dpkg -l` (after chrooting in the correct directory)